# Is it possible to create a queue of object arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, queue

For example:

```
class Hooks {


 public:
 std::string text;
 std::string hookfont;

 HookFromEncouter()
 {
     text = "Would you befriend an elf? ";
     hookfont = "COPRGTB.ttf";
 }

 HookFromEncouter(string text1, string hookfont1)
 {
     text = text;
     hookfont = hookfont1;
 }

 };
```

I need to store arrays of this object in a queue:

How do I create and access such a queue with object arrays of variable length? Or static length?

Such as:

```
queue<Hooks[]> Hooks_queue;
```

Great. This code gives me an error though:

```
vector<Hooks> hooks_import;
hooks_import.push_back(Hooks());
hooks_import.push_back(Hooks());

Hooks_queue.push(hooks_import);
```

Error: No instance of overloaded function

Comment: `queue<vector<Hooks>>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the internal arrays are meant to be variable length or the length won't be known until run-time you could use

```
std::queue<std::vector<Hooks>> Hooks_queue;
```

If the size is fixed and known at compile time, you could use

```
std::queue<std::array<Hooks, N>> Hooks_queue;
```

Where `N` is the size of each `array`

Comment: Great. This code gives me an error though:

 vector<Hooks> hooks_import;
 hooks_import.push_back(Hooks());
 hooks_import.push_back(Hooks());

 Hooks_queue.push(hooks_import);

Error: No instance of overloaded function

Comment: Great. This code gives me an error though:
'code' vector<Hooks> hooks_import;
 hooks_import.push_back(Hooks());
 hooks_import.push_back(Hooks());

 Hooks_queue.push(hooks_import);
'code'

Error: No instance of overloaded function

Comment: Yes just did. So how do I fix this? Thank you

Comment: std::queue<std::vector<Hooks>> Hooks_queue;

As you instructed